# Pb convert weight

Tags: php

I try to use a class to convert weight, kg in gr ....
But I have always 0 like value.

```
public function prepareRules() {
  $Db = Registry::get('Db');
  $Language = Registry::get('Language');

        $Qrules = $CLICSHOPPING_Db->prepare('select r.weight_class_from_id, 
                                              r.weight_class_to_id, 
                                              r.weight_class_rule 
                                      from :table_weight_classes_rules r, 
                                            :table_weight_classes c 
                                      where c.weight_class_id = r.weight_class_from_id
                                      ');
  $Qrules->setCache('weight-rules');
  $Qrules->execute();

  while ( $Qrules->fetch() ) {
    $this->weight_classes[$Qrules->valueInt('weight_class_from_id')][$Qrules->valueInt('weight_class_to_id')] = $Qrules->value('weight_class_rule');
  }

  $Qclasses = $Db->prepare('select weight_class_id, 
                                                weight_class_key, 
                                                weight_class_title 
                                          from :table_weight_classes 
                                          where language_id = :language_id
                                          ');
  $Qclasses->bindInt(':language_id', $Language->getID());

  $Qclasses->execute();

  while ( $Qclasses->fetch() ) {
    $this->weight_classes[$Qclasses->valueInt('weight_class_id')]['key'] = $Qclasses->value('weight_class_key');
    $this->weight_classes[$Qclasses->valueInt('weight_class_id')]['title'] = $Qclasses->value('weight_class_title');
  }
}

public function convert($value, $unit_from, $unit_to) {
  if ( $unit_from == $unit_to ) {
    $convert = number_format($value, $this->precision, static::getNumericDecimalSeparator(), static::getNumericThousandsSeparator());
    return $convert;
  } else {
    $convert = number_format($value * $this->weight_classes[(int)$unit_from][(int)$unit_to], $this->precision, static::getNumericDecimalSeparator(), static::getNumericThousandsSeparator());

    return $convert;
  }
```

If I try to convert something
$products_weight = $Weight->convert(5, 2, 3);

5 is weight (value)

2 is kg ($unit_from)

3 is oz ($unit_to)

```
var_dump($value); ==> ok
var_dump($this->weight_classes[(int)$unit_from][(int)$unit_to]); ==> always 0
```

Comment: What driver are you using? It looks like you are trying to bind tables. But you a) aren't binding anything and b) cant bind tables (or not with any driver I know of)

Comment: Solve, error in my first db, change inside the code above for good synthax